# What should I do if I am using an Apache License 2.0 library in my android application?

Tags: android, licensing

If I am using a library that is licensed under Apache License 2.0, do I need to credit the author in my application? If yes then where exactly in the application (in description of play store or any other area in app itself)? And how exactly should I credit the author (by just providing the link to license)? Please help.

I checked and even the glide and picasso libraries are licensed under Apache License 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you are releasing the source code of your application you need to include a copy of the apache license in your source code (note if the library itself already has a copy of the license thats enough).

Its also good practice to credit the author yes, include somewhere in your application (perhaps an about page) a list of libraries used and their owners/which license they fall under.

Comment: I disagree with this summary of the Apache2 obligations. It is incomplete and inaccurate. It is better to follow the original language (there are 4 items to follow when you distribute the Work or Derivative Work)

Answer (score 2):

I actually find that the [Apache 2 License](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) is pretty easy to read and understand. The clauses are clearly worded.
Here is a pretty short summary of your obligations (you better read the original!)

- You must always give a copy of the Apache License (regardless if you distribute your SW as source or compiled)
- You must always identify if you have changed any of the source
- In the source code of your program you must keep all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices of the original library
- If there is a NOTICE file in the library, you must ship all applicable parts of it with your software.